# Modify JSF h:link href result

Tags: java, jsf, components, jsf-2, facelets

I'm curious about the possibility to alter `href`attributes of all generated links.

Let's assume I have a web page which looks something like this:

```
<div>
  <h:link outcome="/foo.xhtml" value="a link" />
  ...
  <h:link outcome="/bar.xhtml" value="another link" />
</div>
```

The resulting output would be something like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="/foo.jsf">a link</a>
  ...
  <a href="/bar.jsf">another link</a>
</div>
```

I'm now trying to alter the URL generated as `href` attribute within the generated content and let's say add a directory to all the generated links (depending on their content), so that I get the output

```
<div>
  <a href="/a-new-location/foo.jsf">a link</a>
  ...
  <a href="/another-new-location/bar.jsf">another link</a>
</div>
```

Is there a quick and easy way to achieve this or do I have to implement the component and the renderer completely on my own and copy the logics used by the standard implementation?

Comment: What version of JSF r u using?

Comment: oops! i always forget to look at the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a quick note to let you know that I solved the problem by replacing the standard `ViewHandler` with my own `ViewHandler` implementation that overrides the `getBookmarkableURL` method and performs the replacement upon the URL generated by the parent `ViewHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no a direct solution without using some renderer modification.

I propose a solution that works when the href is a valid JSF page and you want the transformation of the outcome be made before is evaluated by the navigation handler.

First, a bean for outcome transformation:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class OutcomeTransformer {

    public String getNewOutcome(String outcome){
        if(outcome.equals("/page.xhtml")){
            return "/directory/"+outcome;
        }else if(outcome.equals("/anotherPage.xhtml")){
            return "/anotherDirectory/"+outcome;
        }else{
            return outcome;
        }
    }

}
```

Seccond, use a composite component for wrapping the link. The outcome of the h:link is transformed by the bean.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="outcome"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:link outcome="#{outcomeTransformer.getNewOutcome(cc.attrs.outcome)}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

And finally, here is a using page.

```
<ez:myLink outcome="page.xhtml" value="A page"/>
<br/>
<ez:myLink outcome="anotherPage.xhtml" value="Another page"/>
```

Of course, you can use a expression directly in the h:link but with the composite component all the logic of the transformation is in only one place.